# Ruby Active record model, How to return selected attributes and override one attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, enums, model

I have model called UserUrl inside this i have enum:

```
enum category: { custom_url: "custom_url", email_share: "share_url" }

has_rich_text :email_content
```

When ever i have called the users_url.share_url will give activerecord relation object which is correct but for email_content i want **email_content.body&.to_trix_html**.

So i need to create a custom method in UsersUrl model called

```
def self.custom_response
  select(:id, :name)
end
```

but i want email_content as a email_content.body.to_trix_html.

What is the good way to do it?

Comment: With no much details it'll be tricky to come up with an accurate solution. For example, can you provide the UsersUrl class? Also do you have any issue using `to_trix_html` ?

Comment: This is a very obvious [X Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). `.select` is used to change the SELECT clause in a SQL query while `to_trix_html` is the result of transforming the results from one more queries in Ruby. The solution to the actual underlying problem is more likely something like writing a simple getter method that  does `email_content.body.to_trix_html.`  or using a decorator.